# How Can I use Naive Bayes Classifier, SVM, and Maximum Entrophy in stanford classifier

Tags: java, svm, stanford-nlp, text-mining, naivebayes

Currently, I am making a citation sentence classifier with Naive Bayes algorithm, SVM, and Maximum Enthrophy and for now my data is 110 non citation sentence and 10 citation sentence. I was using code to classify from stanford classifier examples, and it turns out good. But the classifier is Quasi-Newton. How can I use Naive Bayes classifier, Support Vector Machine, and Maximum Entropy? I already try to edit the prop file and add "useNB=true", but it turns out all data is non citation sentence class. I already read the javadoc at http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/ColumnDataClassifier.html and I don't know where do I put setClass for Naive Bayes algorithm

Answer (score 0):

By default, the classifier will run a maximum entropy (i.e., logistic regression) classifier -- programmatically, `LinearClassifier.java`. QNMinimizer is the Stanford implementation of an L-BFGS minimizer, used to optimize the maxent objective. The flag `useNB=true` I believe is correct for switching to Naive Bayes. For running an SVM: in theory CoreNLP has a wrapper for SVMLight, but at that point you may as well run SVMLight directly.

Is your training data unbalanced to begin with? With a balanced training set, it would be strange to put all the sentences into one class.